# NHibernate one-to-one in a legacy database with a composite-key

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, legacy-database

We have a legacy Database that we want to read data from using NHibernate.
The tables that we want to map are the following:

#### Users

- PK - UserId
- PK - GroupId
- LocationSource
- etc...

#### Locations

- PK - UserId
- PK - GroupId
- PK - Source
- X
- Y

Every user has one or more locations. A location can be entered from different sources, which are identified by the `Source` column.
the Users table's L`ocationSource` column holds the most relevant location source for that user.

In the current application we're writing, we need only the last location.
this is done mainly for performance reasons, we don't want to load all the locations (using outer join)
whenever we load a User (Lazy Loading is out of the question either).

The classes will look something like that:

```
public class UserKey
{
    public int UserId {get;set;}
    public int GroupId {get;set;
}

public class Location
{
    public double X {get;set;}
    public double Y {get;set;}
    public LocationSource Source {get;set;}
}

public class User
{
    public UserKey Id {get; set;}
    public Location Location {get;set;}
}
```

I cannot figure out how to map the database scheme to those class.
Everything I tried failed so far.

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: UserKey seems to be a composite key for User table, I think that's what seems to be confusing. You can map User and Location once you figured out the composite key. Check this out. Might help. http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2010/06/30/nhibernate-and-composite-keys.aspx

Comment: How is last user's location defined?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it.

User would contain both a List (Locations) and a reference to the current Location (Source) therefore you get the current Location per User and the historic list of a User's Location's.

User.Locations and User.Source will both lazy load by default but you can use any of the query options to eager load User.Source to get the current location for your benefit.

When you add a Location to a User via the Locations property you will obviously need to manage the Source reference as well.

If you would like the XML mapping files I can provide as well as I have used Fluent NHibernate 1.1.

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual int GroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Source { get; set; }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        var t = obj as User;
        if (t == null)
            return false;
        if (UserId == t.UserId && GroupId == t.GroupId)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (UserId + "|" + GroupId).GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class Source
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Source Source { get; set; } 
    public virtual string X { get; set; }
    public virtual string Y { get; set; }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        var t = obj as Location;
        if (t == null)
            return false;
        if (User == t.User && Source == t.Source)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (User.GetHashCode() + "|" + Id).GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(x => x.UserId, "UserId")
            .KeyProperty(x => x.GroupId, "GroupId");
        HasMany(x => x.Locations);
        References(x => x.Source).Columns("UserId", "GroupId", "LocationSource");
    }
}

public class LocationMap : ClassMap<Location>
{
    public LocationMap()
    {
        CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(x => x.Source, "Source")
            .KeyReference(x => x.User,"groupId","userid");
        References(x => x.User).Columns("userid","groupid");
    }
}

public class SourceMap : ClassMap<Source>
{
    public SourceMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
    }
}
```